# Pass struct by value

Tags: c#, .net, structure, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Given the following code, I'm curious to know how to avoid the following exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at PBV.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Documents and Settings\tmohojft\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects\PBV\Program.cs:line 39
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PBV
{
class Program
{
    struct structItem
    {
        public int y { get; set; }
        public int z { get; set; }
    }

    struct testStruct
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public List<structItem> items { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        testStruct a = new testStruct();
        structItem b = new structItem();

        for (byte i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            b.y = i;
            b.z = i * 2;
            a.items = new List<structItem>();
            a.items.Add(b);
        }

        testStruct c = new testStruct();
        c = a;

        int counter = 0;

        //exception thrown on line below
        foreach (var item in a.items) {
            structItem d = item;
            d.z = 3;

            c.items[counter] = d;
            counter++;
        }

        a = c;
    }
}
}
```

I originally tried to simply put the following in the second foreach:

```
item.z = 3;
```

But that caused the following error:

```
Cannot modify members of "item" because it is a "foreach iteration"
```

I tried to create a temporary object in order to be able to modify the struct data inside the foreach, but I recieve the exception above. My best guess is because my temporary struct is saving a reference to the original struct rather than the value itself - which is leading my original struct to be updated when my temporary struct is.

So my question is:
**How do I pass this struct by value rather than reference? Or is there an entirely different way to get around this issue?**

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers guys. I'm aware that the list is a reference type, but does that make it impossible to pass by value instead of reference then?

Comment: friends don't let friends use mutable structs: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs.aspx

Comment: There's no real "automatic" way to deep copy of an object.  If you wanted to do something like that, you could implement IClonable on your testStruct structure and write the code to create a new list in the cloned object and then copy every item from the original list to the cloned one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a little confused by what your example code is trying to do, but I think perhaps part of your confusion may be that when you set `c = a`, you expect it to make a copy of the list.  It does not.  While the structure itself is a value type, the items property it contains is not.  List<> is a reference type, so when you set `c = a`, it copies that `items` reference to c.  So, when you enter the loop, both a and c contain a reference to the same list object.  Therefore, when you modify the list while you are enumerating through it, it will always fail.

A simple way to avoid this is to iterate through a static copy of your list:

```
foreach (var item in a.items.ToArray())
```

Comment: +1, but OP it's a big no-no to modify an enumerable WHILE you are enumerating it. Think about choosing a different strategy for what you want to do.

Comment: @tejs I admit this isn't my real code, just a simplified version of something else I'm trying to do. I know it's not ideal, but I'm just assigning a value to an previously empty variable, I'm not actually modifying any data that was set previously (except to null).

Comment: @SteveDog: Looks like it works. I'll upvote once I can (in a few more hours) but I want to see if there's an answer to my idea of fixing it as well before marking anything as answer. Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried making it a `List<object>`? Then it should box the struct as though it was a reference type. However, that comes at the cost of the intellisense without a type conversion.

Comment: It did occur to me, but i'd rather not create a class for this data structure, as it's fairly simple (basically just a result set) and I don't feel it's needed.

Comment: @Mansfield I added and additional comment to my answer which may help.

Answer (score 2):

`a.Items` and `c.Items` are still the very same List instance. You could just iterate over it with an old-fashioned `for` loop instead. That way you're not using any enumerator and thus can modify the list as you want.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Items.Count; i++)
{
    c.Items[i] = whatever;
}
```

You're keeping a counter anyway, so this seems like the natural way to do it. For performance reasons you might want to store the list size in a local variable if you don't intend to add or remove any items from it.

Comment: Another useful thing to mention is that if you are looping through like this, you can start at the end and step backwards to the beginning of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Mutable value object (struct) are much harder to deal with than immutable. Consider making the struct immutable and redesigning your code around it.

It is often easier to not use struct at all unless you know exactly where benefits and pain points are. Try switching your code to class instead and measure if performance meets your goals.

Note: `c = a;` is shallow copy (which is not really making second copy of your `testStruct` at all, but refers to `a`), it looks like you want deep copy - consider making it constructor instead and copy array instead of referencing it.

Answer (score 1):

In some applications, mutable value types offer the most appropriate semantics.  The inherent meaning of a `List<someValueType>` is often much clearer than that of a `List<someMutableClassType>`(*), regardless of whether or not the value type supports any method of mutation other than all-field-copy(**).  Unfortunately, the built-in collections like `List<T>` really do not support mutable value types very well, since they do not expose any means of mutating the stored items other than all-field-copy.

I would suggest that in many cases, you may be best off not using `List<T>` but instead simply keeping a `T[]` and an item count.  If you want to add an item to the collection, check to see whether the count is greater than or equal to the length; if so, double the length.  Then store the new item in the slot indicated by the count and increment the count.

If you really want to use a `List<someStructType>`, you can use the approach suggested by others, iteratating through items to be modified by using an integer loop on the index, rather than using a `foreach`.  When working with mutable structs, however, the ability to say `myArray[i].X = i+4;` instead of `var temp=myList[i]; temp.X = i+4; myList[i] = temp;` is worth the slight hassle of dealing with array expansion.

(*) The semantic meaning of a `List<MutableClassType>` can vary, depending upon whether each list item holds the only reference to a distinct object instance, or whether instances holding the same data may be shared.  No such ambiguity exists with a `List<StructNotContainingMutableClassReferences>`.

(**) If `X` and `Y` are storage locations of the same struct type `S`, the statement `X = Y` will copy all public and private fields from Y to X, in some arbitrary order.  The statement `X = new S(params);` creates a new instance of struct type `S` with all fields blank, calls the constructor on it, and then copies all of the fields from that new instance to `X`.  Consequently, if any fields a value-type instance can ever hold non-default values, those fields will be mutable if the instance is stored in a mutable storage location.  All fields of value-type instances stored in immutable locations will be immutable.  The only thing making a value type "mutable" or "immutable" does is affect the ease of changing its contents.